# How to SELECT customers with orders before specific date

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, max, having

I have two table.

```
Table 'customers': customer_id, date_register, name

Table 'orders': order_id, customer_id, order_date
```

Now I want the customers who have orders before specific date and have NOT after that date.

I am using this query:

```
SELECT customer_id
  FROM orders
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT order_id
                 FROM orders
                WHERE order_date <= '2020-05-12 23:59:59')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT order_id
                     FROM orders
                    WHERE order_date > '2020-05-12 23:59:59')
```

But I get empty result.

What SQL query should I use?

Comment: *I want the customers who have orders before specific date and have NOT after that date* what is not clear in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT customer_id 
FROM orders
GROUP BY customer_id 
HAVING MAX(order_date) < '2020-05-13';
```

Comment: simple answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try selecting the customer  based  on the two range using  main query and a subquery in left join then checking for not matching id

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id 
     FROM orders 
     WHERE order_date > '2020-05-12 23:59:59') t ON t.customer_id = orders.customer_id
                                                 AND orders.order_date <= '2020-05-12 23:59:59'
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Is there any syntax error near : 'orders.order_date <= '2020-05-12 23:59:59'' ?

Comment: answer updated ..  missing AND between conditions

Comment: `WHERE t.id is null AND orders.order_date <= '2020-05-12 23:59:59'` is correct?

Comment: yes should work also with WHERE t.id is null AND orders.order_date <= '2020-05-12 23:59:59'  because the orders table is in main from clause  ..